# How to tell octave that the index is meant to be a matrix, not a vector

Tags: matlab, types, vector, matrix, octave

When indexing into a vector with a matrix of variable dimensions, how do I indicate to octave that the index is a matrix and not a vector?

For example, in the following code, on the fourth iteration, Octave sees the index as a row-vector and it transposes the return value of the indexing operation to be a column vector (to match the vector being indexed into rather than the one used for indexing).

When I run:

```
v = rand(16,1);

t = magic(4);

f = @(m)(sum(m, 1));

for i = 4:-1:1
    s = t(1:i,:);
    f(v(s))
endfor
```

I get:

```
ans =

   1.47780   2.28879   1.29786   2.98981

ans =

   1.24705   1.31940   0.87484   2.18276

ans =

   0.89387   0.55288   0.50312   1.61950

ans =  1.9294
```

See that on the first three iterations, the answer is a row-vector, but on the last iteration, the answer is a singleton value.

How do I tell octave that the variable s is supposed to be a matrix, not a vector and that the result of the indexing operation should always be the same shape as s?

Comment: I tagged this question matlab because I believe the same problem exists in Matlab as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to work around this "feature" would be something like this:

```
v = rand(16,1);
t = magic(4);
f = @(m)(sum(m, 1));

for i = 4:-1:1
    w(1:i,:) = v(t(1:i,:));
    f(w(1:i,:))
end
```

This forces the output of `v` to be stored in `w` in the proper orientation. Note that I pass `w(1:i,:)` into the function `f` rather than just `w` because of your reverse-indexed `for` loop.

This is a surprising common pattern and is a useful way of repeatedly setting the columns of a matrix equal to a row vector or the rows of a matrix equal to a column vector without needing to perform a transpose or even know the orientation of the vector (who knows the the Matlab/Octave JITs do under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

> How do I tell octave that the variable s is supposed to be a matrix, not a vector

In Matlab/Octave matrix and vector is the same thing. Vector is just a 1xm or mx1 matrix.

In sum function dimension option only works if both dimensions are bigger than 1.

Just make vector a special case.

```
for i = 4:-1:1
    s = t(1:i,:);
    if i~=1
        f(v(s))
    else
        v(s)'
    end
end
```

Comment: The dimension option for sum always works (whether dims are 1 or not).  That is not the problem (although it appears you did identify the issue since you were forced to transpose v(s) when i==1 which is what this is all about). f(v(s)') should work in place of your v(s)', but I was looking for a more elegant solution without the conditional.